# how to change the char* global?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

**how to change the char* string3 global?**

```
int add_on(void);
char* string1 = "hello ";
char* string2 = "world ";
char* string3 ;

int main(){            
    add_on();// calling add_on();
    printf("%s\n",string3); // print

}

int add_on(){

    char * string3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(string1)+ strlen(string2));
    strcpy(string3, string1);
    printf("This is string 3: %s\n",string3);
    strcat(string3, string2);
    printf("This is string 3: %s\n",string3);

    return 0;
}
```

```
This is what I get from the console: 

This is string 3: hello 
This is string 3: hello world 
(null)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Why it NULL? how can I change the global char* in function as i change inside of the add_on()?**

Comment: `char * string3 = ` -> `string3 =`

Comment: you are overriding the globally scoped `string3` with another locally-scoped variable of the same name.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was my mistake

Comment: Please put this in an answer and mark it. It will help others with similar problems. And it will save us time by not needing to read answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, `string3` must not be declared again inside the `add_on()` function.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) is some background about the scope of variables in C.

In addition to this, it would be cleaner to `free` the allocated memory before terminating and to return a value from `main`.

```
int add_on(void);
char* string1 = "hello ";
char* string2 = "world ";
char* string3;

int main()
{
    add_on(); // calling add_on();
    printf("%s\n", string3); // print
    free(string3);
    return 0;
}

int add_on()
{
    string3 = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(string1) + strlen(string2));
    strcpy(string3, string1);
    printf("This is string 3: %s\n", string3);
    strcat(string3, string2);
    printf("This is string 3: %s\n", string3);
    return 0;
}
```